Переменная в скрипте PostgreSQL
Всем привет,
База PostgreSQL 9.6.20.
Постоянно возникает ошибка на 'varchar'. Почему?
DECLARE NZ varchar := '2021777147';
BEGIN
select id from cmf_task where task_entity_id = (select id from cmf_document_common where reg_number = @NZ);
END;

Вот сообщение об ошибке:
SQL Error [42601]: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar") Position: 12 ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar") Position: 12 ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar") Position: 12

Скрипт в DBeaver.

Вот только не надо "рассказов по мотивам". Сообщение об ошибке должно быть приведено полностью и абсолютно точно, вплоть до количества пробелов и мест перевода строк.

Вот сообщение об ошибке:
SQL Error [42601]: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar")
Position: 12
ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar")
Position: 12
ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar")
Position: 12

https://dbfiddle.uk/Lod4ccuv PS. Добавляйте факты в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий.

А без добавления функции?
У меня права только на чтение.

Эммм... а как? анонимный блок кода? так он как бы не допускает SELECT "в никуда".
